# Interpolation of Polynomial using Lagrange

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, interpolation

$f(x) = x^3  + 2x^2 + x + 1$. Find a polynomial of degree $4$ that interpolates the values of $f$ at $x = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2$.

I was trying to use the Langrange algorithm, but I think i'm doing it wrong as I'm not getting a correct answer.

Comment: What did you do? It's much easier to know what you're doing wrong that way. At the end of the day, you're just going to get back $f$.

Comment: I think I am reading the notation wrong. It could probably see what I'm doing wrong once someone shows me the solution. Assuming they write out the steps

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial is
$$P_4(x)=\frac{(x+1)(x-0)(x-1)(x-2)}{(-1)(-2)(-3)(-4)}f(-2)+\\ 
\frac{(x+2)(x-0)(x-1)(x-2)}{(1)(-1)(-2)(-3)}f(-1)+\\
\frac{(x+2)(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)}{(2)(1)(-1)(-2)}f(0)+\\
\frac{(x+2)(x+1)(x-0)(x-2)}{(3)(2)(1)(-1)}f(1)+\\
\frac{(x+2)(x+1)(x-0)(x-1)}{(4)(3)(2)(1)}f(2)$$

Comment: Ah! I was close. I was doing the iterations wrong

Comment: Glad to help out, @nlane